# Inexplicable code in 'deep learning with Python book'

Tags: keras, deep-learning

In Francois Chollet's book 'Deep Learning with Python', he gives a simple VAE model, in the end, he wants to generate some novel digits as follows:

Just look at the separated part of the code (in the middle). He takes a sample(Z_sample), then repeats it HUH! then feed all of that to the generator (the decoder), and he tells the decoder that this is a batch!!, and anyway, in the end, he just takes one of the outputs!!  x_decoded[0] as you can see later.

```
n = 15
digit_size = 28
figure = np.zeros((digit_size * n, digit_size * n))
grid_x = norm.ppf(np.linspace(0.05, 0.95, n))
grid_y = norm.ppf(np.linspace(0.05, 0.95, n))
for i, yi in enumerate(grid_x):
   for j, xi in enumerate(grid_y):
       z_sample = np.array([[xi, yi]])
```

> ```
> >     z_sample = np.tile(z_sample, batch_size).reshape(batch_size, 2)
> >     x_decoded = decoder.predict(z_sample, batch_size=batch_size)
> ```

```
       digit = x_decoded[0].reshape(digit_size, digit_size)
       figure[i * digit_size: (i + 1) * digit_size,
       j * digit_size: (j + 1) * digit_size] = digit
```

Question: Why did he do that? I removed that nonesense and everything worked.
Second question:  what on earth is the point of having an argument for batchsize in the predict method?? I mean, it is understandable in the training phase, but not in the inference phase.

Comment: Keras can do the predictions in batches if you provide a `batch_size` argument. I am not sure about your first question though. I can see it can be removed. I don't know why he wanted the slice to be repeated for the entire batch.

Comment: Perfect! you got my point. I removed it anyway and everything is fine. Back to the second question, I still don't get! why would you predict in batches? because you cannot predict wholesale? any application or case where you needed that?

Comment: You can of course predict the whole. In cases, if the data doesn't fit your RAM, you can go predicting in batches. But I am not exactly sure why it was needed in this example. My point is... it can be done, it's possible and sometimes needed as an answer to your "what on earth is the point".

Comment: Also in Keras 1, `BatchNormalization` used different `mode`s where predicting in batches can make some difference in the inference values. This has been removed in Keras 2.

Comment: Batches are the solution when training or predicting and you cannot fit the model in RAM, specially when multiple samples need prediction. Its also faster to predict multiple samples at the same time as you can profit from parallelization in CPU and GPUs.